# SoX detecting volume is always near max

Tags: audio, sox

I'm trying to detect speech volume above a threshold in short, 2-3 second, audio files with sox but it's always coming out about 90% max volume regardless of silence or noise.

This is the command i'm using (i've tried varying the scale option):

```
sox noise.wav -n stats -s 99
```

If i shout and have the microphone in my mouth or bash it i can get a detectable difference of about 95% volume but it is a desktop style microphone. Playing back the audio files there is an audible silence recorded but there is still a big distinction when speaking from a distance.

Is there a setting i'm missing or has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: Have you tried 0.99 instead of 99?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but i had tried a variety of different values on the scale without any luck. I ended up using the python AudioSegment library instead.